# Stripe form not creating token

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, stripe-payments

Read all the docs, multiple Stripe examples, and done the SO rounds.

The customer actually gets created just fine with a token of nil. I run into the error though when I try and make a charge to that customer, because of course they don't have a card.

HTML HEADER

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/" %>

    <script type="text/javascript">
Stripe.setPublishableKey(<%= STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>);

  jQuery(function($) {
        $('#cleaning-form').submit(function(event) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

        Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
    });
  });

var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#cleaning-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and re-submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
```

FORM (it's multiple partials, this is the applicable portion)

```
<%= form_for @booking, :authenticity_token => true, :html => { :id => "cleaning-form" } do |f| %>
    <h4>Credit Card Number</h4>
  <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, :class => "valid payment-form", name: nil, :placeholder => "Card Number", :data => {:stripe => 'number' }, :tabindex => 1, :autofocus => true %>

   <h4>Card security code (CVC)</h4>
  <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil,:class => "valid payment-form" , name: nil, :placeholder => "3 or 4 digits", :data => {:stripe => 'cvc' }, :tabindex => 2 %>

    <h4>Expiration date</h4>
  <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month", :data => {:stripe => 'exp-month' } } %>

  <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year", :data => {:stripe => 'exp-year' } } %>
```

PARAMETERS

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"/D9mJRkSX7Wf51QHl+vzWPpweYsUUIfCcJrlbCZfPLE=",
"booking"=>
{"job"=>
{"bedroom"=>"1 bedroom", "bathroom"=>"1 bathroom", "extras"=>""},
"hours"=>"2",
"user"=>
{"name"=>"RERE234234",
 "address"=>"34",
 "state"=>"34",
 "city"=>"4",
 "zipcode"=>"34",
 "email"=>"343223@AERAER.COM",
 "phone"=>"(434) 343-4343"},
"time"=>"Sat Mar 08 2014 11:30:00 GMT-0700 (MST)"},
"commit"=>"Book cleaning",
"action"=>"create",
"controller"=>"bookings"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was my public key didn't have quotes around it.

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey(<%= STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>);
```

got changed to:

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>');
```

And now it works fine.